# Multiple groupby functions based on whether column names are in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two DataFrames.

One summarises London Census data in Wards. There two types of columns, ones that can be summed because they are absolute numbers, and ones that need to be averaged because they are percentages.

I want to group the Census data by boroughs. I have in another DataFrame a list of columns that have percentages and should be averaged when grouped by, the other columns should be summed.

What I have so far:

```
test = censusDF.groupby(['Borough'], as_index = False).agg({pc_cols_df:'mean',
                                                        i for i not in pc_cols_df : 'sum'
                                                       })
test
```

Which gives me this error;

```
  File "<ipython-input-84-6a20dc571632>", line 2
  for i not in pc_cols_df : 'sum'
  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've also tried:

```
test = censusDF.groupby(['Borough'], as_index = False).agg({pc_cols_df.values.tolist():'mean'})
test
```

And get this error;

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Example columns names that should be averaged:

```
age=All ages: Population % by age
age=0 to 4: Population % by age
age=5 to 7: Population % by age
age=8 to 9: Population % by age
age=10 to 14: Population % by age
age=15: Population % by age
```

Sample Census DataFrame:

```
id, Name,   Borough N of all usual residents,   distance to work=Work mainly at or from home: Population N by distance travelled to work,   distance to work=Other: Population N by distance travelled to work, Total distance to work (km),    Average distance to work (km),  age=All ages: Population % by age,  age=0 to 4: Population % by age,    age=5 to 7: Population % by age,    age=8 to 9: Population % by age,    age=10 to 14: Population % by age

E05000039,  Thames, BarkingDagenham,    10728,  315,    569,    44684.2,    13.8,   100,    12.9,   5.8,    3.4,    6.9
E05000040   Valence BarkingDagenham 9867    240 526 41897.9 13.2    100 9.8 4.7 2.8 7
E05000041   Village BarkingDagenham 10787   238 585 51537.5 14.7    100 9.7 4.3 2.6 6.8
E05000042   Whalebone   BarkingDagenham 10575   299 567 54068.4 14.1    100 8.9 4.3 2.6 6.5
E05000043   Brunswick Park  Barnet  16394   832 892 72028.8 11.7    100 6.4 3.6 2.6 6.6
E05000044   Burnt Oak   Barnet  18217   611 1226    68000.4 11.4    100 8.4 4.6 2.8 7.2
E05000045   Childs Hill Barnet  20049   1301    1300    69172.1 9.7 100 7   3.4 2.1 5.4
E05000046   Colindale   Barnet  17098   583 1145    65002   11.2    100 8.5 4.2 2.4 6
E05000047   Coppetts    Barnet  17250   936 1036    75344.7 11  100 7.3 3.7 2.1 5.4
E05000048   East Barnet Barnet  16137   776 863 79660   12.8    100 7.2 3.9 2.4 6
E05000049   East Finchley   Barnet  15989   883 946 72995.5 11.1    100 7.1 3.7 2   4.9
E05000050   Edgware Barnet  16728   999 887 69743.2 12.2    100 7.8 4.3 3   7
E05000051   Finchley Church End Barnet  15715   1272    842 62194.5 10.9    100 6.6 3.7 2.4 5.1
E05000052   Garden Suburb   Barnet  15929   1485    636 59431.5 10.4    100 7.5 3.7 2.4 5.7
E05000053   Golders Green   Barnet  18818   1155    986 53137.1 9.2 100 9.3 5.6 3.1 7.9
E05000054   Hale    Barnet  17437   967 980 76701.1 12.4    100 8.2 4.1 2.4 6.9
E05000055   Hendon  Barnet  18472   1099    1219    66641.3 10.5    100 8.1 3.7 2.2 5
```

Comment: You're misusing dictionary comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a syntax error because you're miss-using dictionary comprehensions. And you can't state `i for i not in pc_cols_df : 'sum'` and expect python to know you're referencing columns in censusDF (or at least I assume you're trying to).

Change pct_cols_df to a list (there's no need for this to be a dataframe) or at least change it to a series of column names and then the following code should accomplish what you want:

```
censusDF.groupby('Borough', as_index = False).agg({**{col: 'mean' 
for col in pc_cols_df}, **{col: 'sum' for col in [col for col in censusDF.columns if col not in pc_cols_df]}})
```

I don't know what python you're using so dictionary merging might break depending on that.